# How do I convert a JavaScript date to a MySQL datetime format?

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, datetime

For example, my JavaScript date function returns:

```
Tue Apr 29 2014 14:40:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

Is there any function I can use to convert this into the proper DateTime format to save this in MySQL? It should look like:

```
2014-04-29 14:40:00
```

Comment: your server side script used to add the data to mysql should be able to do it and convert to proper date format before adding to mysql.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize DateTime was the same as TimeStamp - thought they were different formats.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp....Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp
(this mysql function)

or if you want to give format to the